# Infinite loop in wordpress WP_Query loop

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the following code, i'm not sure having context of what happens within the while loop is hugely important. The issue lies with the `continue;` in the if statement. The condition in the if is met, and so `continue;` is reached. this created an infinite loop though. I can not understand why this is the case though?

Could anyone suggest why WordPress can not handle a `continue;` in a WP_Query loop?

```
while ($latest_events->have_posts()) {

        $id = get_the_ID();             
        $custom_fields = base_get_all_custom_fields($id);           
        $event_type = $custom_fields["course/event_type"][0];

        if(isset($event_type) && strpos_arr($event_type, array('Training')) !== false ){
                continue;
        }  

        $latest_events->the_post();
        get_template_part('partials/latest-espresso-events');   
 }
```

Comment: are you trying to exit the loop at that point or is it deliberate that you create the infinite loop?

Comment: I'm trying to 'skip' the iteration and go to the next object

Comment: @Liam, did you check the solution I gave? Does it work?

Comment: @Dekel it does, apologies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't call `$latest_event->the_post()` the loop counter will not advanced, therefor you will have an infinite loop.

You must call `$latest_event->the_post()` before the `continue;` statement to make sure you go to the next post (otherwise the `$latest_events->have_posts()` will always return `TRUE`).

```
        if(isset($event_type) && strpos_arr($event_type, array('Training')) !== false ){
            $latest_event->the_post();
            continue;
        }
```